# Blender 2.79: Baking Problems

Tags: materials, texture-baking, baking, unity

Ok, so I'm trying to bake a texture I made in Blender for a Unity game model ,since just importing the blend file ignores materials. However, I've run into a problem.

Here's what the model looks like before baking...

[image]

And here's what it looks like after.

[image]

I tried unwrapping the model and *then* baking with color Diffuse, and got the same results, while baking in Blender Render just gave me an error message saying there was nothing **to** bake.

Is there something I'm doing wrong when it comes to this model, or should I just start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Each selected polygon stores the data memory of a manually selected image. Blender Internal and Cycles both have different ways for you to state the image you wish to bake onto.

## Blender Internal

Bakes a selected model's attributes to the active image for that
selected in the UV Editor window. (for each meshes inner mesh-piece
e.g a door)

**Note:** You must be in edit-mode **first** before choosing the UV-editor stated bake image.

[image]

## Cycles

Bakes a selected model's attributes to a manually stated image in the node-editor.

**Note:** The image node for **each** material that is used in the baking process **must** be selected.

[image]